# Can a Jquery mobile app open android video player to play video?

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, video

I am creating a cordova jquery mobile app. which play video in it. I have tried video tag  but it is not showing the video only sound is played .

Now I want to open android video player to play my video url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: [FileOpener Plugin](https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener)

Video tag have too much issue with different platform and version on Android, if you want to avoid that, [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) is a good solution.